# Ive made some code using turtle that needs user interaction and its not working when opening the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

It works if you copy and paste the text into idle but not just opening the file

This is the code i dont know whats wrong ignore all the open files and audio bits it will be part of a bigger game and it will come with the files but there are not important in this.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import turtle, winsound, os

def k1():
    screen.onkey(None, "w")
    cy = cursor.ycor()
    cym = cy+100
    cursor.goto(-250, cym)
    credits.color('black')
    if cursor.ycor() == 300:
        cursor.goto(-250,200)
        screen.onkey(k1, "w")
    elif cursor.ycor() == 200:
        play.color('white')
        screen.onkey(k1 , 'w')
    else:
        screen.onkey(k1, "w")
    
def k2():
    screen.onkey(None, "s")
    cy = cursor.ycor()
    cym = cy-100
    cursor.goto(-250, cym)
    play.color('black')
    if cursor.ycor() == 0:
        cursor.goto(-250,100)
        screen.onkey(k2, 's')
    elif cursor.ycor() == 100:
        credits.color('white')
        screen.onkey(k2 , 's')
    else:
        screen.onkey(k2, "s")

def k3():
    screen.onkey(None, 'return')
    if cursor.ycor() == 200:
        os.startfile('dunegon1.py')
    elif cursor.ycor() == 100:
        os.startfile('credits.txt')

#winsound.PlaySound('main menu.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)

#logo.left(90)      #this goes here in final deployment
#logo.forward(350)  #but too annoying for testing 

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(800,800)
screen.title('Rendering')
screen.tracer(False)

turtle.register_shape('logo.gif')
logo = turtle.Turtle()
logo.shape('logo.gif')
logo.penup()
logo.speed(1)

cursor = turtle.Turtle()
cursor.shapesize(6, 4, 2)
cursor.penup()
cursor.hideturtle()
cursor.speed(0)

play = turtle.Turtle()
play.hideturtle()
play.penup()
play.shape('circle')
play.shapesize(3, 3, 3)

credits = turtle.Turtle()
credits.hideturtle()
credits.penup()
credits.shape('circle')
credits.shapesize(3, 3, 3)

logo.left(90)
logo.forward(350)

cursor.goto(-250, 200)
cursor.showturtle()

play.goto(-200, 200)
play.write('     Enter dunegon', font=('arial', '40'))
play.color('white')
play.showturtle()

credits.goto(-200, 100)
credits.showturtle()
credits.write('     Credits', font=('arial', '40'))

screen.onkey(k1, 'w')
screen.onkey(k2, 's')
screen.onkey(k3, 'Return')

screen.listen()
screen.tracer(True)
screen.title('Menu')
screen.mainloop()
```

If you put it in idle it works fine but not from the file other files work but not this one.
Any ideas?
I have now tryied it on another device and it works fine?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're referring to. Can you clarify what you're trying to do here, and what exact problem you're having? Thanks. If you're trying to use code in another .py file, make it a module and use the `import` keyword, then call a function from the file to run code in it.

Comment: no its the actual file when I try to open it in file explorer it opens then appears to crash with out saying anything

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Do not open Python files from the File Explorer, this effectively won't do anything.

Running a Python file can be done on the command line:

```bash
python -m <module>
```

where `<module>` is the name of the file you want to run, without the `.py` extension.

For a more streamlined experience, I'd recommend Visual Studio Code and its Python extension. This will allow you to detect problems in your code as you type it, and if you want to run your active python file you can do it with a simple button press.

Comment: Main problem is that im doing this on my school where i have no accsess to cmd #